# free allocated memory by posix_memalign by freeing a pointer that points to this memory

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

When allocating memory using `posix_memalign` does calling `free` on the pointer that points to the pointer of the allocated memory free all the allocated memory?
In this example, when I `free` `pointer_to_data` and then look at the original pointer I still see the same data in all allocations but not the last ones!

```
unsigned char *data = nullptr;
unsigned int  data_size = 512;

posix_memalign((void **) &data, 16, data_size);
memset(data, 0, data_size);

for (int i = 0; i < data_size; i++){
    data[i] = 0xff;
}

unsigned char *pointer_to_data = data;
free(pointer_to_data);


for (int i = 0; i < data_size; i++){
    printf( " %x ",data[i]);
}
```

ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  10  0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When allocating memory using `posix_memalign` does calling `free` on
> the pointer that points to the pointer of the allocated memory free
> all the allocated memory?

It's unclear whether "the pointer that points to the pointer of the allocated memory" belies a misunderstanding or whether it's just poor wording.  I don't see a way to interpret it that matches the example presented.

To free allocated memory, including memory allocated via `posix_memalign`, one must pass to `free()` a pointer to the base address provided by the allocation function.  `posix_memalign()` is unusual among the standard allocation functions in that it writes that pointer via an out parameter instead of returning it, so here ...

> ```
> unsigned char *data = nullptr;
> unsigned int  data_size = 512;
>
> posix_memalign((void **) &data, 16, data_size);
> ```

... the base address in question is recorded in variable `data`, whose own address is passed as the first argument to `posix_memalign` to enable that function to modify its value.  The pointer value that `posix_memalign` writes there is the one that must subsequently be passed to `free`, but all C function arguments are passed by value, so only the value passed can make a difference, not the expression that produced that value.

Thus, if you do this ...

> ```
> unsigned char *pointer_to_data = data;
> ```

... then you have just copied the (pointer) value of `data` to variable `pointer_to_data`, so that it is true that `data == pointer_to_data`.  You may then free the allocated block by passing the (same) value obtained from either variable to `free()`.  This is a valid way to free the allocated space:

> ```
> free(pointer_to_data);
> ```

---

You go on to remark that

> In this example, when I free pointer_to_data and then look at the
> original pointer I still see the same data in all allocations but not
> the last ones!

Freeing the allocated space makes it available for reallocation, and *terminates the lifetime of the allocated object*.  Attempting to access the value of an object whose lifetime has ended produces undefined behavior.  If you suppose (unsafely) that you can continue to use a pointer to the freed space to examine the no-longer-allocated memory then there is no reason to expect the memory to have changed, but also no reason to expect that it has not.

In particular, memory allocators do not typically go out of their way to overwrite the contents of freed memory blocks, but it may in some cases serve a purpose to modify some or all of that memory, or some or all of it may be reallocated and possibly overwritten soon after it becomes available, such as in the calls to `printf` in your example code.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned char *pointer_to_data = data;
```

This is not a *pointer* to the pointer, it's a *copy* of the pointer, also called an *alias*.  It points to the same address as `data` itself does.  Calling `free(pointer_to_data)` has precisely the same effect as calling `free(data)`.

Freeing a block of memory is not guaranteed to make its previous contents inaccessible.  Rather, trying to access that region of memory is *undefined behavior*.  You might see the data that was previously there, if the allocator has chosen to reserve that region of memory for future allocations.  You might see metadata placed there by the allocator itself.  You might see data placed there by a different part of the program, if the space has been allocated again.  You might get a segmentation fault, if the memory has been returned to the OS and unmapped.  Literally anything could legally happen, and most of the possibilities will be ones you won't like.  So it is your responsibility to ensure that your program just doesn't do that, and to not write code like what you have written.

To repeat, the distinction between `data` and `pointer_to_data` has nothing to do with this.  You'd have seen exactly the same (undefined) behavior if you had done `free(data)` instead.

(If the data stored in that block was sensitive, e.g. encryption keys, then you need to ensure that you overwrite it *before* you `free()` it; you can't rely on `free()` to do that for you.  This is a more difficult thing to do properly than it would appear, since other copies of the data may exist elsewhere and you have to be sure to overwrite them all.  If this is your situation, you should probably get expert advice.)

Note that everything mentioned above is just the same for `malloc()` as for `posix_memalign()`.

If you really wanted a pointer to the pointer, you would write

```
unsigned char **actually_a_pointer_to_data;
actually_a_pointer_to_data = &data;
```

In that case `free(actually_a_pointer_to_data)` would itself be undefined behavior, because `actually_a_pointer_to_data` does not point to the same address as `data` does, and in particular is not the address that was returned by `posix_memalign` which is the only one you may legally `free()`.  However `free(*actually_a_pointer_to_data)` would be equivalent to `free(data)`.